# Vim regex matches unicode characters are as non-word

Tags: regex, vim, unicode

I have the following text:

```
üyü
```

The following regex search matches the characters ü:

```
/\W
```

Is there a unicode flag in Vim regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such flag (yet).

Some built-in character classes (can) include multi-byte characters,
others don't. The common `\w` `\a` `\l` `\u` classes only contain ASCII
letters, so even umlaut characters aren't included in them, leading to
unexpected behavior! See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60600/18876.

In the `'isprint'` option (and `'iskeyword'`, which determines what motions like `w` move over), multi-byte characters 256 and
above are always included, only extended ASCII characters up to 255 are specified with
this option.

Answer (score 3):

I always use:

```
ASCII                           UTF-8
-----                           -----
\w                              [a-zA-Z\u0100-\uFFFF]
\W                              [^a-zA-Z\u0100-\uFFFF]
```

Comment: This does not include the digits, while `\w` do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\%uXXXX` to match a multibyte character. In that case…

```
/\%u00fc
```

But I'm not aware of a flag that would make the whole matching multibyte-friendly.

Note that with the default value of `iskeyword` on UNIX systems, `ü` is matched by `\k`.

Answer (score 0):

very often I find \S+ takes me where I want to go. i.e:
`s/\(\S\+\)\s\+\(\S\+\).*/\1 | \2/`  selects "**wörd1 w€rd2** but not word3" and replaces the line with "wörd1 | w€rd2"