# Vim to copy first word in line and print it after that word separated by 4 spaces

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim and would like copy the first word in certain lines and simply paste it after that word separated by 4 spaces.  Below is an example.

```
football
run
phone
watch
```

Would then become:

```
football    football
run    run
phone    phone
watch    watch
```

I would only like to be applied to lines 186 to 1413.  I'm able to do this using Vim visual mode but there has to be a quicker way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `substitute` command and a line range:

```
:186,1413s/^\w\+/&    &/
```

`186,1413` is the range of lines (start,end) to operate on. `s` is short for `substitute` (see `:h substitute`), which does a regular expression search-and-replace.  `^\w\+` matches any word characters (alphanumeric and underscore, with no spaces). `&    &` replaces the matched word with itself, four spaces, and itself again.

Any text after the first word will be appended to the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned some of the characters in the word are special characters such as ö,ë,ä,’  so the word up until these characters are copied. So the word, "o’leary" will only be copied up until the ’ so only "o" will be copied to the end of the line.  And the word goöball, only "go" will be copied to the end of the line.

Comment: You can use `[a-zA-Z\u0100-\uFFFF]` (per [vim-regex-matches-unicode-characters-are-as-non-word](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31178814/719547)) instead of `\w` to bluntly match Unicode characters too, but that won't match apostrophes. You might be better off with a match-to-first-space regex instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:normal` command:

```
:186,1413norm! yw4A ^[p
```

the `^[` you press `ctrl-v` then `ESC`